# Streamlit multiselect filter using different dataframes

Tags: python, web-applications, dashboard, streamlit, social-media

I have this code below that plot three columns from different dataframes. Now I add a Streamlit multiselect filter so that you can add or remove plots. The code is fine it is just that I want to add the the streamlit multiselect filter. See the code below:

```
socio_media = ['facebook','twitter','linkedin']
options = st.multiselect('Compare your social media platform', options = socio_media, 
                    default=socio_media)




fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=facebook_df['Date'],
    y=facebook_df['Impressions'],
    name='Facebook',
    mode='markers'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=twitter_df['Date'],
    y=twitter_df['Impressions'],
    name='Twitter',
    mode='markers'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=linkedin_df['Date'],
    y=linkedin_df['Impressions'],
    name='LinkedIn',
    mode='markers'
))

fig.update_layout(
    title= select+' '+'Over Time',
    xaxis=dict(title='Date'),
    yaxis=dict(title= select)
)
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to put a conditional on each trace to match the multiselect?

Comment: @MathCatsAnd Yes. But if there is any other way you can show me. At the moment multiselect is not connected to the plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is put a conditional on each trace. For example:

```
fig = go.Figure()

if 'facebook' in options:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=facebook_df['Date'],
        y=facebook_df['Impressions'],
        name='Facebook',
        mode='markers'
    ))

# etc
```

Abstractly, you put the pieces of code that add each trace inside a conditional for its respective selection:

```
import streamlit as st

socio_media = ['facebook','twitter','linkedin']
options = st.multiselect('Compare your social media platform', options = socio_media, 
                    default=socio_media)

if 'facebook' in options:
    st.write('Adding Facebook...')
    # Add trace

if 'twitter' in options:
    st.write('Adding Twitter...')
    # Add trace

if 'linkedin' in options:
    st.write('Adding LinkedIn...')
    # Add trace
```